# Junit test for unmarshalling method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, unmarshalling

I have to test my methods for unmarshalling functionality and I don't know how to do it. Can someone explain me?

Here are my methods:

```
@Service
public class MapperServiceImpl implements MapperService {

    public void mappingContent(String directoryPath, String fileName) throws JAXBException {
        File xmlFile = new File(directoryPath + "/" + fileName);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Menu.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Menu menu = (Menu) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);

        displayMappingContent(menu);
    }

    public void displayMappingContent(Menu menu) {
        List<Content> contents = menu.getContents();
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);

        System.out.println("Type : " + menu.getType().toUpperCase());
        contents.stream()
                .flatMap(content -> content.getFoods().stream()).toList()
                .forEach(food -> System.out.println("NR. " + count.getAndIncrement()
                        + "\nName : " + food.getName() + "\nPrice : " + food.getPrice()
                        + "\nDescription : " + food.getDescription() + "\nCalories" + food.getCalories() + "\n"));

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you don't know? Seems pretty straightforward to me, there are just 2 methods, both are public and only depend on the inputs.

Comment: @m0skit0 I am beginner and It's my first Junit test. I don't know the steps to test it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to test because your methods operate by side effects (that is, printing to a `PrintStream`) instead of returning values.

A simple approach to make your code more testable is to create two more methods in your class:

```java
@Service
public class MapperServiceImpl implements MapperService {

    public void mappingContent(String directoryPath, String fileName) throws JAXBException {
        File xmlFile = new File(directoryPath + "/" + fileName);
        displayMappingContent(unmarshallMenu(xmlFile));
    }

    public void displayMappingContent(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println(renderMenu(menu));
    }
    
    public String renderMenu(Menu menu) {
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
        List<Content> contents = menu.getContents();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Type : " + menu.getType().toUpperCase());
        contents.stream()
                .flatMap(content -> content.getFoods().stream()).toList()
                .forEach(food -> sb.append("NR. " + count.getAndIncrement()
                        + "\nName : " + food.getName() + "\nPrice : " + food.getPrice()
                        + "\nDescription : " + food.getDescription() + "\nCalories" + food.getCalories() + "\n"));
        return sb.toString()
    }
    
    public Menu unmarshallMenu(File xmlFile) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Menu.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Menu menu = (Menu) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
    }
}
```

Now the original two methods are trivial, and the new ones are simple to test.

You could also split your service into three: a `@Component` to unmarshall, a `@Component` to render menus, and the existing service which is a client of those components. Then when you test the service you can mock those components.